# Combine JS Variable With HTML ID Name - DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that shuffles the numbers 1-3
I then assign each string in the array to a variable B1 - B3

I need to combine the B1 - B3 variables to the HTML IDS
document.getElementById("p1").value = S1;

Example Instead Of Putting p1 I want to put p + B1, because B1 would be a number between 1 - 3

I've tried document.getElementById("p" + B1).value = S1;

but I don't get a console error and it doesn't put a value to the element.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];



  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3];
shuffle(arr);
//alert(arr);

var B1 = arr[0];
var B2 = arr[1];
var B3 = arr[2];

document.getElementById("p1").value = S1;
document.getElementById("p2").value = S2;
```

I want to combine the B variables to the element ID call

I want to call the element p+B variable

```js
// Define  Min Number Range 

var Min = 10;
var Max = 40;

//Set NumberValues S1 + S2 == MainNumber

var S1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);
var S2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);

// Set Main Number Value & Random Number Value

var MainNumber = S1 + S2;
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);

// Assign Button Position

// Button Click Counter

var clickCount = 0;

function clickCounter() {
    
    clickCount ++;
    
    if (clickCount > 2) {
        
        clickCount = 0;
        console.log("Loser");
    }
    
    console.log(clickCount);
    
}

// Array Shuffel + Function

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  
     
  
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3];
shuffle(arr);
//alert(arr);

var B1 = arr[0];
var B2 = arr[1];
var B3 = arr[2];

// Assign Button Positions

document.getElementById("p1").value = S1;
document.getElementById("p2").value = S2;
document.getElementById("p3").value = RandomNumber;
document.getElementById("p4").value = MainNumber;
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = MainNumber;

console.log(MainNumber);
console.log(B1);

// Console Logs
```

```html
 <input class="bmain w-button" id ="p1" type="button" value="" onclick="userInput1.value += value, clickCounter() ">
 <input class="bmain w-button" id ="p2" type="button" value="" onclick="userInput2.value += value, clickCounter()   ">
```

Comment: what happens when you `console.log( "p" + B1 );`?

Comment: `document.getElementById("p" + B1)` should work. So you're saying that the code you posted (where `"p1"`, `"p2"` etc are hard-coded) works perfectly, but when you try to use `"p" + B1`, it stops working? Could you try using `"p" + B1` again, and if it still doesn't work, post the non-working code? It's possible you just have a typo somewhere.

Comment: [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117934/concatenation-js-var-to-dom)?

Comment: Okay, I just got it to work using "p" + B1, before It was just putting an empty value into the inputs, don't know what changed thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You are be able to do the document.getElementById("p" + B1).value = S1;

Your problem is somewhere else. I don't think we have all of your code, for example: userInput1.value is undefined.

Check it out:

```js
// Define  Min Number Range 

var Min = 10;
var Max = 40;

//Set NumberValues S1 + S2 == MainNumber

var S1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);
var S2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);

// Set Main Number Value & Random Number Value

var MainNumber = S1 + S2;
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);

// Assign Button Position

// Button Click Counter

var clickCount = 0;

function clickCounter() {
    
    clickCount ++;
    
    if (clickCount > 2) {
        
        clickCount = 0;
        console.log("Loser");
    }
    
    console.log(clickCount);
    
}

// Array Shuffel + Function

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  
     
  
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3];
shuffle(arr);
//alert(arr);

var B1 = arr[0];
var B2 = arr[1];
var B3 = arr[2];

// Assign Button Positions

document.getElementById("p"+B1).value = S1;
document.getElementById("p"+B2).value = S2;
document.getElementById("p"+B3).value = RandomNumber;
document.getElementById("p4").value = MainNumber;
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = MainNumber;

console.log(MainNumber);
console.log(B1);
```

```html
<input class="bmain w-button" id ="p1" type="button" value="" onclick="userInput1.value += this.value; clickCounter() ">
 <input class="bmain w-button" id ="p2" type="button" value="" onclick="userInput2.value += this.value; clickCounter()   ">
  <input class="bmain w-button" id ="p3" type="button" value="" onclick="userInput2.value += this.value; clickCounter()   ">
    <input class="bmain w-button" id ="p4" type="button" value="" onclick="userInput2.value += this.value; clickCounter()   ">
 <input type="text" id = "userInput1">
 <input type="text" id = "userInput2">
```